# @BeforeMethod(TestNG) and @BeforeTest(TestNG) counterpart while writing test cases in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, testng, protractor

I am writing test cases using Protractor and Jasmine framework.
But as I have background of writing test cases in Java using TestNG framework, my mind keep on forcing me to use something like **@BeforeMethod** and **@BeforeTest** of TestNG framework in Jasmine, along with Groups property of TestNG.
Are there any counterparts for the same in Jasmine framework?
I have used **afterEach** and **beforeEach** method but it applies for every it() function of every describe, there is no method to apply running on the basis of some Groups.

Thanks,
Mohit

Answer (score 0):

In a spec file
`beforeAll` will run before ALL of the specs (before beforeEach)
`beforeEach` will run before each `it`
`afterEach` will run after each `it`
`afterAll` will run after ALL of the specs (after afterEach)

In protractor.conf.js
`beforeLaunch` will run right before the browser is available
`onPrepare` will run right after the browser is available (before the specs)
`onCleanUp` will run right after the last spec finishes